# Fedora 15 with PAE

Tags: memory, fedora-15, pae

I installed FC 15 onto a laptop that previously had XP installed. While XP reported that Physical Address Extension was enabled, I am unable to find any reference to it in Fedora. How can I tell if the kernel I'm running supports it, and how can I enable PAE if it's not currently supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `uname -a` or `cat /proc/version` and see what the kernel string looks like - for example:

> Linux aa1.localdomain 2.6.38.8-35.fc15.i686.PAE #1 SMP Wed Jul 6 14:29:06 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

If 'pae' (or 'PAE') isn't there then your kernel doesn't support PAE

If you do not have the PAE kernel installed, issue the following command (as root):

```
yum install kernel-PAE
```

Then reboot

Just to make sure your processor supports PAE, you should do the following first:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i PAE
```

If there's no sign of pae (or 'PAE') in the output, your processor doesn't support that mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep address /proc/cpuinfo`, and the output should tell you if PAE is supported.

Comment: What should he look for? Could you provide a sample output?